# Opel Zafira A enters safe mode above 3500 rpm

Tags: opel, egr, zafira

I have Zafira A (2002) 2.0 dti and recently when engine reaches about 3500 rpm (regardless gear or speed) it enters safe mode and won't go above 2500 rpm, also loses power. Ofcourse, after I stop the car and remove the key and then start it again, the problem is gone and it doesn't occur again until the engine reaches mentioned 3500 rpm. I cleaned the EGR valve and the problem seem to disappear, now since I am far from car expert I was wondering if this was the only issue or there could be more problems or faulty parts?
Also I noticed these parts which I couldn't identify and I was wondering if someone can tell me what they are. Here are the pictures:
[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you been able to read the codes? I think that's going to give you a large clue what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! The confusing part is there is no error. I tried to read it by applying brake and throttle simultaneously for four seconds (which usually gives the 4-digit code by blinking the check engine light) but there was none. But while driving (when the rpm goes above 3500) this check engine(maintenance) light appears and car went into safe mode. This was the case before cleaning the EGR. So I am wondering if this was the only problem or perhaps I may have a larger issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that I can write an coherent answer but I'll try to bring up some points:

- Those two marked parts are solenoid vacuum valves. The upper one controls the egr valve. The lower one controls the switchover for the swirl flaps in the intake manifold. Both egr valve and the swirl flaps are a frequent root cause for a lot of issues.
- In my experience periodic cleaning of the egr valve is needed when one doesn't routinely use his car for prolonged high-load drives.
- Should the issue persist you could try to plug the vacuum line of the swirl flap unit. A ruptured membrane in the actuator could destroy the entire vacuum in the system, causing a malfunction in the egr. The same for any other mayor vacuum leak.
- The brake and throttle combination won't reveal everything. A cheap ELM 327 reader might be more useful as you can read the codes while engine is running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the detail explanation. It is very helpful, I got all the information I needed. And I will get the reader for sure.